# How tall was Brutus?

Tags: roman-empire, julius-caesar

Brutus was an important figure in the Roman Empire and also played a large role in Shakespeare's iconic work, *Julius Caesar*. After researching many different sources, I have yet to identify the height of the man who assassinated Caesar(Brutus, in case you didn't get it). If at all possible, I would like to know the answer and the sources.

Comment: It seems entirely possible that it was never recorded.

Comment: There are known marble busts of Brutus, and I wonder if his height could be estimated from those.

Comment: May I ask why you need this information?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read between the lines: nobody (as far as I know) wrote about his height. That almost certainly means he was of average height. If he had been exceptionally tall or short, someone probably would have written about it.

Comment: I thank you all for your feedback. When I get back to school from Christmas Break, I will be able to finish my project. Thank you all so much for taking the time to answer this.